# Who was Edmund Cleary Cass?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, daredevil-2015

In *Daredevil* season 3, episode 11, Karen Page & Matt Murdock have to hide out inside a crypt within a Catholic Church. The plaque on the casket they hide inside says:

> Edmond Cleary Cass
>
> February 17, 1883
>
> October 3, 1948

Here's a screen capture:

[image: Karen climbing in the plaque]

Who was Edmond Cleary Cass?

---

Note that internet searches for this name turn up several pages that appear to be real people, but either there is scant information about them, the dates don't match up, or the name is only a partial match.

---

I did turn up one [auction site apparently selling props from the show](https://www.barnebys.com/auctions/lot/lot-280-bloodied-crypt-casket-08dpgekivof), including this casket & plaque. It's notes about the casket are pasted below. What I find interesting about this is that since this was a prop, someone clearly took the time to decide on the name and manufacture the plaque, and then it was prominently featured. So much time and effort suggests there is probably something significant about the name.

> Lot # 280: Bloodied Crypt Casket
>
> Daredevil (TV Series)
>
> A bloodied crypt casket from the episode 'Reunion' (311) of Marvel's Daredevil. In the episode, Matt Murdock and Karen Page hide from the
>   police and FBI in an empty casket in the church basement. This lot
>   consists of a gray plaster, resin and wood casket with a plaque
>   featuring the name 'Edmond Cleary Cass' and a crucifix on the
>   interior. It is in good overall condition with some wear and faux
>   blood stains applied by production. This is an oversize lot which
>   requires special shipping. - Dimensions: 72 x 24" x 13" (182.5 cm x
>   60.5 cm x 33 cm)"

---

One further search result claims that they [found no significance](https://www.moviemistakes.com/tv11013/questions) in the name. But it seems hard to prove a negative and they don't seem to do so.